# How to pass a named function with parameter in jquery instead of anon function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to pass a named function with parameters to a jquery function as an argument instead of an anonymous function. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
$('body').bind("click", saySomething);

function saySomething(word)
{
    console.log(word);
}
```

Now I think I'm right in saying that I can't add the parentheses to the `saySomething` parameter in my jQuery call, so how can I pass in the parameter?

**Note:** This may be a duplicate of another question, but to the the difficut nature in trying to explain this question to SO and Google I've posted this.

Comment: Why don't you want to just do this:  $('body').bind("click", function(e){ saySomething(arg); });  ?, as in what is the reasoning?

Comment: The reasoning behind it, is if I wanted to bind a number of elements to the same behaviour, I figure I could encapsulate it in one function and just refer to it. That doesn't appear to be working as expected:  http://jsbin.com/dufew/15/edit

Comment: All three answers solved my question in different ways. How do I accept an answer?

Comment: @JasonMortonNZ: You choose the answer that helper you the most (e.g. you learned most from it, it's the solution you are settling with, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is perfectly fine, since the `click` event passes an `event` object as the first parameter, the variable `word` in your `saySomething` function will be that `event` object.

If you want to define yourself what word will be, there is no way around wrapping it in some other function and call it with the value you want.

Comment: So looking at a quick JSbin example I've put together. Why isn't this working as expected: http://jsbin.com/dufew/15/edit

Comment: @JasonMortonNZ Because you had an error in it, i fixed it see: http://jsbin.com/dufew/16/ You forgot the single quote closing the string inside the console.log(); JSBin shows you the error if your code throws them. Just look at the very bottom of the javascript sourcecode.

Comment: As I learnt that there's no way around wrapping my function call in a function, which is something I didn't know, and hence was the source of my issue. I'm accepting this as my answer. But a big thanks to everyone to answered and helped out :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('body').bind("click", function(){saySomething(par);});
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [`$.proxy`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), or the native [`.bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind),  but `this` wouldn't be set to the correct element anymore:

```
$('body').bind("click", $.proxy(saySomething, null, 'hello'));
```

Answer (score 1):

> The reasoning behind it, is if I wanted to bind a number of elements
>   to the same behaviour, I figure I could encapsulate it in one function
>   and just refer to it

You can still refer to the same function call, it is just a little more verbose.  There's no way around that.

```
$('.item1').bind("click", function(e){ saySomething('one'); }); 
$('.item2').bind("click", function(e){ saySomething('two'); }); 
$('.item3').bind("click", function(e){ saySomething('three'); });
```

Also, your example in the comment seemed to work okay for me.